# Pyinstaller: Why some command actions don't work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller

I designed a simple Python GUI with Tkinter. It includes a button which performs an action when it is pressed. Originally, it opens a new subprocess in order to run an external software. The code works fine when ran like a script, but when I converted into an application using Pyinstaller it doesn't work. No errors or warnings appear during the conversion (in Anaconda power shell) and during the .exe execution.
So I decided to simplify it, showing a messagebox when the button is pressed. Once converted with Pyinstaller, again nothing happens.
Here is the command I use for the conversion

```
pyinstaller --onefile -w ProgramName.py
```

And this is the content of the script, for the GUI generation

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter.constants import *

# %% ROOT
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("710x630+410+100")
root.minsize(120, 1)
root.resizable(1,  1)
root.title("myGUI")
root.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
root.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
root.configure(highlightcolor="black")   

# %% BUTTON OPEN FILE
Button_OpenFile = tk.Button(root)
Button_OpenFile.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, padx=10, pady=50)
Button_OpenFile.configure(activebackground="#ececec")
Button_OpenFile.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
Button_OpenFile.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
Button_OpenFile.configure(compound='left')
Button_OpenFile.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
Button_OpenFile.configure(foreground="#000000")
Button_OpenFile.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
Button_OpenFile.configure(highlightcolor="black")
Button_OpenFile.configure(text='''OPEN FILE''')
Button_OpenFile.configure(command=lambda: tk.messagebox.showinfo(
        title='Information',
        message='This is an information message.'))

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tkinter.messagebox` is a module and needs to be imported separately and explicitly with the rest of your imports in order to use it.

To solve your problem all you need to do is add an import statement:

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import tkinter.messagebox  # <-- added this
from tkinter.constants import *

# %% ROOT
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("710x630+410+100")
root.minsize(120, 1)
root.resizable(1,  1)
root.title("myGUI")
root.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
root.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
root.configure(highlightcolor="black")   

# %% BUTTON OPEN FILE
Button_OpenFile = tk.Button(root)
Button_OpenFile.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, padx=10, pady=50)
Button_OpenFile.configure(activebackground="#ececec")
Button_OpenFile.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
Button_OpenFile.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
Button_OpenFile.configure(compound='left')
Button_OpenFile.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
Button_OpenFile.configure(foreground="#000000")
Button_OpenFile.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
Button_OpenFile.configure(highlightcolor="black")
Button_OpenFile.configure(text='''OPEN FILE''')
Button_OpenFile.configure(command=lambda: tk.messagebox.showinfo(
        title='Information',
        message='This is an information message.'))

root.mainloop()
```

Additionally it's always good practice to compile your application without the `-w` flag the first time so that you can see the error messages that pop to make debugging much easier.  Then once your app runs smoothly, add the `-w` back to your pyinstaller command.

Comment: Thank you for your tips. They worked for me. But what about an external program such as myProgram.exe? I was able to run it with the subprocess module. But how can I import it in order to be exectuted also after the conversion with pyinstaller?

Comment: @eljamba you can still do that you just need to bundle the executable with the scriipt when you compile pyinstaller

Comment: What you mean with bundle the executable with the script? They are in the same folder...

Comment: When I move into the _dist_ folder and run the executable, in the command window it is said: _"myProgram.exe" is not recognized as an internal or external command, an executable program or a batch file_. Keeping the two executables in the same folder, makes the application working properly. Is there a way to import "myProgram.exe" in order to distribute a single .exe file?

Comment: @eljamba  Yes there is.  Open a new question on SO  and describe your problem and I or someone ellse will be able to show you how.